# How to keep track of beginning of single linked list?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have the following implementation of node.

```
   struct node*{
    int data;
    node* next;}
```

Now I add some values and create a linked list but I want to keep track of beginning of the linked list.
Any suggestions?

Comment: A pointer to the first node, perhaps?

Comment: How? Can you tell in code format?

Comment: The variable would be something like `node * head;`. If you don't know how to declare and update a pointer, you should re-read that chapter of your introductory book.

Comment: If you make another class called LinkedList.  In it you can have a node pointer variable called head.  You can also include functions like adding and removing from the list.

Comment: You mean something like a=*head; and later return &a

Comment: @user3780835: No, don't do anything like that. Re-read the chapter on pointers, and just use `head` as a pointer. `a=*head` would copy the first node, and `return &a` would return a dangling pointer to that copy, after it's been destroyed, which is very bad.

Comment: Fix the compiler error first. `struct node*{` is wrong. Semi colon missing at end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Bravo!

It's good to want to know how to implement linked list!
But you should add a superior instance which permit you to manage it more easily:

## Class Implementation

It's kinda the heavier way to manage it, a class which manage your linked list could be good if you want to keep trace of your actions(and don't mess beetwen two list)! it could be something like this:

```
class my_linked_list {
private:
 struct node {int value; struct node* next;}; //by doing this only you can manage your linked list!
 struct node* m_head;

public:
 my_linked_list() : m_head(nullptr) {}//here you just instantiate teh manager, not the head!

 void append_value(int a);// here is some
 int  pop_value();        // methode which allow you to manage your nodes easily!

};
```

## Only Function Implementation

A light version could be to manage it with only function, as such:

```
node* create_head(int);//create your first node
void  append_value(node**,int); // manage your node, call it like append_value(&head, value); because head can move from nullptr -> heap allocated struct!
int   pop_value(node**); // same as previous, heap allocated-> nullptr
void  delete_list(node**);//delete all and put your head to nullptr
```

## Edit

As @anatolyg said the previous example was more like a C example! the good way to do it in c++ is:

```
node* create_head(int);//create your first node
void  append_value(node*&,int); // manage your node, call it like append_value(&head, value); because head can move from nullptr -> heap allocated struct!
int   pop_value(node*&); // same as previous, heap allocated-> nullptr
void  delete_list(node*&);//delete all and put your head to nullptr
```

## Voila!

For more advise just comment!

Comment: In c++ (unlike c) it's not necessary to use a pointer-to-pointer - one should use a reference-to-pointer instead, to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 0):

To make an empty singly-linked list:

```
int main()
{
    ...
    node* head = nullptr;
    ...
}
```

Then, you can use functions to add elements to this list:

```
...
node* head = nullptr;
add_element(8, head);
add_element(9, head);
...
```

Here, `add_element` (or any other name) is a function you have to implement.

Note: c++ has a standard library that has singly-linked lists; if you just want to use them, see the description of the [`std::forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) template. But 
I assume you are learning how to implement a linked list, so use the examples above.

Answer (score 0):

I use a pointer to pointer to node that either points to the head or to the last node's next pointer in order to append to an empty or non-empty list with the same code. Note that head will always point to the start of the list (or it will be NULL).

```
typedef NODE_{
NODE_ *next;
int    data;
}NODE;

NODE *  head = NULL;              // ptr to head of list
NODE ** pprevn = &head;           // ptr to head or last node's next pointer.

    *pprevn = new NODE;           // append a new node
    (*pprevn)->data = 1234;       // set data
    pprevn = &((*pprevn)->next);  // advance pprevn
    *pprevn = NULL;               // set next pointer to NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

You should probably start with C Basics first. But here you are:

node firstNode; // this reserves memory on the stack

node * header=&firstNode; // pointer points to start address of firstNode Struct

Comment: Linked lists are usually used with dynamic allocation. Having a pointer to a node on stack invites problems (dangling pointers); it's possible to do it safely but certainly not easy.

Comment: I know but this was just a pointer example. Using alloc and free is obligate. That's why I mentioned "reserves memory on stack".